# how to use contains functions with array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blur

i have an array which contains some values. i want if the textbox's value contains a value from any of the element of that array it will show alert "exists", otherwise "doesn't exists"
I have tried the following code:

```
$('[id$=txt_Email]').live('blur', function (e) {
    var email = $('[id$=txt_Email]').val();
    var array = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];
    if (array.indexOf(email) < 0) { // doesn't exist
        // do something
        alert('doesnot exists');
    }
    else { // does exist
        // do something else
        alert('exists');
    }

});
```

But this is comparing the whole value with the array's element. i want to use contains function as we can in C# with string.Please help me.
I want if user type "test@gmail.com" it will show exists in array. if user enter "test@test.com" it will alert doesnot exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the match not exact string you need to do some thing like

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq3ht/)**

```
arr = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];

alert(FindMatch(arr, 'gmail.co'));

function FindMatch(array, strToFind)
{

    for(i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i].indexOf( strToFind) != -1)
           return true;        
    }
     return false;
}
​
```

Comment: InArray will match the whole value not the some characters,please review my question again i have updated.

Comment: Update my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
$.each(array, function () {
   found = this.indexOf(email);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('blur', '[id$=txt_Email]', function (e) {
    var email = this.value, array = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];

    if (email.indexOf('@')!=-1) {
        if ($.inArray(email.split('@')[1], array)!=-1) {
            alert('exists');
        }else{
            alert('does not exists');        
        }
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TyCt3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
b is the value, a is the array

It returns true or false



function(a,b){return!!~a.indexOf(b)}
```